# In a Maven project, how can you configure the JUnit tests to use the project's own build artifact as a Java agent?

Tags: maven, testing, junit, pom.xml, javaagents

I've created a Maven project. When the project is built, it produces a JAR file that can be used as a Java agent. I have written tests and included them in the project. The tests make sure the Java agent works. In order for the tests to use the Java agent, the JAR file needs to have already been built and an argument needs to be passed to the VM that includes the location of the JAR file. Is this possible with Maven? If so, how?

Comment: This is an integration test where you can use maven-failsafe-plugin for it...